# Python delete attribute method is deleting the value not the attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

In my flask admin app, I have a sqlalchemy orm model, old_model. I want to delete an attribute, action_id from the object. I am doing

```
del old_model.action_id
```

I expect the attribute action_id to be removed from the object old_model. Instead of getting deleted, its value is updated to None and the attribute still exists. How to delete the attribute completely along with the value?

Comment: Have you tried running `delattr(old_model, "action_id")` to achieve this?

Comment: I have tried this as well..dint work

Comment: No too sure then tbh. Just saw this question and was the first thing that came to mind to try from my perspective. Sorry that I can't be of any help on this one - got me stumped!

Answer (score 0):

So this was expected, as SQLAlchemy ORM mapped objects don't support this particular state for an attribute, that is, attribute doesn't exist and would raise AttributeError. for an ORM mapped class, a mapped attribute always defaults to None and/or empty collection. there's a little bit of an introduction to this here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/orm_data_manipulation.html#instances-of-classes-represent-rows

For this particular problem, you can define your column as

```
id = Column('id', String,  FetchedValue())
```

FetchedValue is used when the database is configured to provide some automatic default for a column. So, in this case you only want to ignore the column this would work like a charm. Updated model would look something like:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    pid = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    id = Column('id', String,  FetchedValue())
```